# partial C String initialisation

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, c-strings, string-concatenation, string-literals

In some code I today read, a type of C-String initialisation existed which is new to me.

It chains multiple String-Initialisation like "A""B""C"...

It also allows splinting the String Initialisation to multiple Lines

I set up a small Hello World demo, so you can see what I am talking about:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SPACE " "
#define EXCLAMATION_MARK "!"
#define HW "Hello"SPACE"World"EXCLAMATION_MARK

int main()
{
  char hw_str[] =
  "Hello"
  SPACE
  "World"
  "!";

  printf("%s\n",hw_str);
  printf("%s\n",HW);
  return 0;
}
```

So here are some questions:

- is this valid according to the standard?
- why this works? "abc" is like a array {'a','b','c'} right?, so why are array initialisations concatenated over multiple pairs of "" working?
- has this feature an official name - like when you enter it in google, you find some documentation describing it?
- is this portable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the C Standard (5.1.1.2 Translation phases)

> 1 The precedence among the syntax rules of translation is specified by
> the following phases.
>
> 6. Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated

So for example this part of the program

```
char hw_str[] =
  "Hello"
  SPACE
  "World"
  "!";
```

that after macro substitutions looks like

```
char hw_str[] =
  "Hello"
  " "
  "World"
  "!";
```

is processed by the preprocessor in the sixth phase by concatenating adjacent string literals and you have

```
char hw_str[] =
  "Hello World!";
```

Comment: once I entered the phrase "Adjacent string literal" I found https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/254984/on-concatenating-adjacent-string-literals , which is also a nice hint on that feature.